# Using ctrl alt s to change b-bone size

Tags: rigging, bones, shortcut

I've been trying to change the width of b-bones using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut, when I do that it just selects hp support info instead of allowing me to change width.

Comment: Are you in edit mode when you are trying to change the width?

Comment: Yeah I'm in edit mode and I made sure I had the bone selected but it does that every time.

Comment: Check in User Preferences>Input that the shortcut wasn't changed to something else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open User Preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
2. Switch to **Input** Section.
3. Type in search **Transform**

Under **Pose** you will see the shortcut that is associated with bone transform.

[image]